# Github is not letting me commit files due to nonexistent file that was "supposedly deleted"

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm having a very strange issue. My partner uploaded her changes on github, and for some reason after I synced then it says that I made uncommited changes and deleted some files from the repository. The problem is, that I never did this, I didn't delete anything and I never inserted a file with the names that appear in in the commit page.

I used `git rm --cached 'filename'` but then it tells me it can't do anything because there are no files that match.

So I tried `git add -A` and `git stash` and it all seemed to be fine, but then when I try to make a commit it shows this message again: `Invalid path: 'Website/PHP/speciesSearchByUser*Incomplete*.php'` but like I said, this file never existed in my directory and I never uploaded it. I don't know what my partner did, but my repository is essentially non functional with this.

Does anyone know what causes this and how I can fix it? This is the second time it happens, and the last time I had to delete the repository and create a new one because of it. I do not want to do that again.

Comment: What does `git status` give you?

Comment: Do you have in the repo some file with the same name but different case (upercase vs. lowercase for some part of the filename) in the *same* folder? That wouldn't play well in Windows, and some file would end up missing ("deleted") in the working tree.

Comment: I don't have any files with the same name, no. Git Status says that there is one file that has been modified but it its not the one that appears on the error.

Comment: When you `git fetch` and then  `git reflog`, do you see a commit beyond the one that works? I'm wondering if something made it in and you have to reset HEAD behind it.

Comment: I think that might have done it. After using git add -A  again and then git stash, I reverted my last commit got rid of those files and now everything seems to be working. Although I'm still not clear why this is happening, all I get are files with *incomplete*.php at the end, which I'm not quite sure what that means.